# Displaying label outside canvas/map extend in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer

The first picture shows my map with cadastre (black lines), points with label (orange squares/ red numbers) and a printframe (blue rectangle). The second picture shows what I want in print layout.  It consists of two rectangles, one with the printframe from the map and one with the labels (without map and for now only with manually places text boxes). I want to label the shown points in the map in a second map above (or any other way). The labels need to be placed on the same vertical and horizontal line. I tried to display the labels on x,y (x-fixed for horizontal line), but couldn't get them displayed because items are not in the map/canvas and won't be shown. Furthermore I had some difficulties because of the rotation of the map/printframe.

One solution might be to shown the labels even when the objects are not in the canvas/map extend. Is that somehow possible?

The only other solution I can think of is to get the x,y-values of every point (>500) within every printframe (>100) I have, add a individually x,y-value to every point based on the height of the frame for the labeling and have two maps in the print layout on the top of each other.

As I don't want to do it the other way, it would be nice if someone can give me a hint.

[image: Map with Points, Label und printframe]

[image: Printlayout with Label outside frame]

Answer (score 1):

The common cartographer shivers when seeing this. Please rotate your bottom map by 180 degrees, or even better leave it aligned north from the start. The second map wouldn't be much larger, but much easier to read when aligned north. Also, keeping the labels next to the features is way more efficient and effective when it comes to transporting information.

---

That being said, create another quite narrow map strip above your current second map. Rotate it equally to that map and give it the same scale and the same centroid. Duplicate your layer (via right click) and for the duplicate make the geometry invisible, but turn on the labels and let them be displayed at the center of your features. Display no other features in this map.

Comment: The rotation, the printframe and the position of the labels are more or less given. I can't change them. Your solution only works for points who are placed in line. If I have a printframe from point 4-6 it won't work. Maybe my example was to easy.

Comment: If you're interested in an overall solution, you'll have to provide all the necessary details @Malevil.